# My mother got this tattoo when she was 14 and I’ve always wondered what it meant

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]My mother got this tattoo years ago and I’ve always wondered what it says, I think it’s Chinese but I’m not sure

Answer (score 3):

It looks like "实" - solid/true/real/honest.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not Chinese. It's a Japanese Kanji, which is Chinese character in Japanese.

It has the same meaning with the Chinese character "实". As @r13 said, "实" mean solid/true/real/honest.

Some words for example:

实在 - solid

真实 - true/real

诚实 - honest